# Can I use C code with floating point arithmetics in Linux Kernel code if I use "-msoft-float" compiler flag?

Tags: c, linux, floating-point, kernel

It is not the duplicate question!
I know why FPU module shouldn't be used in kernel.

But what if to compile source code for kernel, which contains floating point operations, using "-msoft-float" gcc compiler flag?

The information about this flag from "man gcc":

> **-msoft-float**    Use (do not use) the hardware floating-point instructions and registers for floating-point operations.  When
>   -msoft-float is specified, functions in libgcc.a will be used to perform floating-point    operations.  When -mhard-float is specified,
>   the compiler generates IEEE floating-point instructions.  This is the
>   default.

Comment: I'm not a kernel dev, but I don't see any reason why this should not work.

Comment: XY problem? If the kernel did make it without floats, there is hardly a reason you will need it right now. You likely have a wrong approach for whatevr you want to achieve.

Comment: @Olaf I am simply trying to build library which is written using floating point numbers (even some non critical part of it) without using FPU. It is the easiest solution in case if we are not worrying about performance.

Comment: @VictorSignaevskyi: And why should that library be used in the kernel? Also: In a kernel performance is **always** an issue!

Comment: @Olaf Your question is not related to the question.